# Substracting 2 Tables in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to subtract values in 2 different pivot tables

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Please help me to subtract values from table 1 - table 2, i have tried Vlookup and sumif but no luck, Any help here is appreciated.

Thanks
Kal

Subtracting 2 tables in excel

Comment: I think it would be better to upload both the sources in Power Query to create a Tabular report by grouping with flex group and then merging both to subtract from one another will be easier. Presently its like create pivot table then do subtraction, long way, instead use one way using PQ

Answer (score 1):

You can try this formula:

`=Table5[@Val1]-INDEX(Table3,MATCH(Table5[@Name1],Table3[Name2]),2)`

without table names

`=$B17-INDEX($A$30:$B$36,MATCH($A17,$A$30:$A$36),2)`

change the corresponding values of the identifiers to your tables

[image]

With OFFICE365 (adjust table names to your sheet's names)

`=VSTACK(Table5[#Headers],HSTACK(Table5[Flex Group],Table5[[Sum of North Europe]:[Sum of West Europe]]-Table3[[Sum of North Europe]:[Sum of West Europe]]))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i wanted a different table to be created with values after seperating, Table1 North - Table2 North & Table1 west - Table2 West

Comment: Added the 365 formula to the answer.